# Change default Grub settings for installation from DVD

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, system-installation, nomodeset

I've got bunch of PCs with NVIDIA GPU to install, that are subject to a "black screen" bug on boot. The problem can be easily solved by adding "nomodeset" to Linux entry in grub.cfg.

I would really like to automate this process by modifying LiveCD ISO so that after OS is installed from it on HDD, "nomodeset" is automatically added to every entry in grub.cfg. Or even better - Grub bootloader is created with nomodeset from the beginning.

How can I do this? I'm experienced Linux user, but I've never modified installation CD before.

Comment: This is a dupe. Now if I can just find what it's a dupe of....